# Hook in Mongoose works in PRE but doesn't work in POST

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Using Mongoose hooks, I need that if the property called outstandingBalance has a value of zero, the status automatically changes to false.

Trying to do this using Mongoose's PRE hook works but only by re-invoking the request after outstandingBalance was already zero before. That is why I have decided to use the POST hook so that once the setting of outstandingBalance to zero is finished, it changes the property from statua to false.

This is the code that I use with PRE that works fine but is not really viable for what I need:

```
SaleSchema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', async function() {
    const docToUpdate = await this.model.findOne(this.getQuery())
  
    if (docToUpdate.outstandingBalance < 1) {
      
      this._update.status = false;
    }
  })
```

So I decided to change PRE to POST but it never works:

```
SaleSchema.post('findOneAndUpdate', async function() {
    const docToUpdate = await this.model.findOne(this.getQuery())
  
    if (docToUpdate.outstandingBalance < 1) {
      
      this._update.status = false;
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the solution to be able to set the status to false depending on the outstandingBalance value using the Pre hook:

```
SaleSchema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', function (next) {

    if(this._update.$set.outstandingBalance < 1) {
        this._update.status = false
    }
    next();
});
```

Many thanks to him for his help as @hoangdv guided me to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

'POST' means all done, there is no action after that(the data is already updated), you have to save it again after setting the status to update the status.

`PRE` hook is correct for your case, just change the condition: Checking on update data instead of current data

```
SaleSchema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', async function() {
    const docToUpdate = await this.model.findOne(this.getQuery())
  
    if (this._update.outstandingBalance < 1 || (!this._update.outstandingBalance && docToUpdate.outstandingBalance < 1)) {
      
      this._update.status = false;
    }
  })
```

Comment: I tried with your code but it gives me the following error: ReferenceError: this_update is not defined

Comment: @OscarDev updated, my mistake `this._update` instead of `this_update`

Comment: Thanks friend but it still doesn't work, I've tried but now it doesn't change even with several tests using pre

Comment: I did a simple test in this way but it does not return anything: ```SaleSchema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', async function() {
   
     if (this._update.outstandingBalance < 1) {
       
         console.log('ok');
         
     }
 })```

Comment: @OscarDev  :-? Updated my answer again. Change the condition.

Comment: Thank you, I tried indicating that when it is less than 5 to be able to do more tests but it only works when the test becomes less than 4, it does not run when it is less than 5 ```SaleSchema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', async function() {

    const docToUpdate = await this.model.findOne(this.getQuery())
  
    if (this._update.outstandingBalance < 5 || (!this._update.outstandingBalance && docToUpdate.outstandingBalance < 5)) {
      
      console.log('ok');
      
      this._update.status = false;
    }
})```

Comment: try to log out the input information right before the if block: `console.log(this._update.outstandingBalance, docToUpdate.outstandingBalance)`

Comment: The answer is undefined :/

Comment: both of them are undefined? :-?

Comment: I tried like this: ```SaleSchema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', async function() {

    const docToUpdate = await this.model.findOne(this.getQuery());

    console.log(this._update.outstandingBalance); // undefined
    console.log(docToUpdate.outstandingBalance); // 3
}) ```

Comment: I understand that console.log(docToUpdate.outstandingBalance)   is the value it has stored before making the change to the new value

Comment: Analyzing a little more with what you have been helping me I have managed to find the solution: ```SaleSchema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', function (next) {

    if(this._update.$set.outstandingBalance < 1) {
        this._update.status = false
    }
    next();
}); ```  

Thank you very much for your help!